# The meaning of the word "bootstrap" in twitter-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What is the meaning of the term 'bootstrap' in twitter-bootstrap? In many gems there is the word 'bootstrap'. I searched for the meaning but could not come to a conclusion. So can someone please give the exact meaning of the word 'bootstrap' in this context?

Comment: "to pull oneself up by one's bootstraps" - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'Bootstrap' normally means you are getting a push-start, so in this case 'twitter-bootstrap' is a collection of UI layouts/components created by 'twitter', to push-start your project.

So using 'twitter-bootstrap' you don't need to worry about browser compatibility, resolution/layout issues , mobile browser problems, because TB has address them already. So you have saved your valuable time to consider your product UI.

And last not the least, never mind about the 'names', just look at what they offer, and if it fits you, just go with it, because in Ruby you have strange names like '[god](http://godrb.com/)', [chef](https://github.com/opscode/chef/), etc..

But I think those are cool, as after all little bit of humour will increase your productivity. :)

Answer (score 0):

Once I've studied a subject named "Basics of the computer hardware" . There were a description of a process preparing the hardware to work . The first phase was "power bootstrap" . I think it's an echo from the passed years in this nowadays bootstrap. Youth years .....

Answer (score 0):

Twitter bootstrap is an CSS and Js Framework which helps to build any types of web user interface and reduces the time in writting css and js for web apps from the scratch

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap:

Sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: Is this an answer in the context of the question? I cannot see how, but am open to hearing it. It seems that the OP knew about Twitter's CSS framework, but they wanted to know the etymology of the word "bootstrap". From a review queue perspective, this strikes me as "not an answer".